# Error al hacer click en DropDwonButton de Flutter por segunda vez

Tags: android, ios, programación-móvil, flutter, dart

Mi problema es:

1. Lleno un DropDownList con registros obtenidos de un API
2. Luego selecciono uno de los items y este evento llena un segundo DropDownList, que al igual que el primero recibe datos de una API
3. Cuando vuelvo a hacer click en el primer DropDownList aparece el error:

**Código del primer DropDownList**

```
 Widget _regionesContainer() {
    return new Container(
      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
        items: dataRegion.map((item) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item['ID_REGION'].toString(),
            child: new Text(item['NOMBRE_REGION'],
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)
          ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        hint: Text("Seleccione región"),
        onChanged: (String newValReg) {
          setState(() {
            _mySelectionReg = newValReg;
            capturaComuna(newValReg);
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: _mySelectionReg,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            );
          });
        },
        value: _mySelectionReg,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0)
    );
  }
```

**Este es el código del segundo DropDownList**

```
    Widget _comunasContainer() {
    return new Container(
        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
          items: dataComuna.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item['ID_COMUNA'].toString(),
              child: new Text(item['NOMBRE_COMUNA'],
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint: Text("Seleccione comuna"),
          onChanged: (newValCom) {
            _mySelectionCom = newValCom;
            setState(() {
            });
          },
          value: _mySelectionCom,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 45.0)
    );
  }
```

**Este es el código de los métodos future:**

```
String _mySelectionReg;
  String _mySelectionCom;

  String urlRegion = "http://www.aquimaestros.cl/am/Region/Read.php";

  List dataRegion = List(); //Lista de regiones
  List dataComuna = List(); //Lista de comunas

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(urlRegion), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      dataRegion = resBody;
    });
    print(resBody);
    return "Sucess";
  }

  Future<String> capturaComuna(String _id) async {
    String urlComuna = "http://www.aquimaestros.cl/am/Comuna/ReadxRegion.php?id_region=${_id}";
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(urlComuna), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      dataComuna = resBody;
    });
    print(resBody);
    return "Sucess";
  }
```

El error se da al dar click por segunda vez en el DropDownList del widget _regionesContainer, este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede sólo si ya seleccionaste un elemento en el segundo `DropdownButton`. Al seleccionar un item estás actualizando el valor del atributo `_mySelectionCom` con el valor seleccionado. Cuando seleccionas otro item en el primer `DropDownButton` necesitas limpiar el atributo `_mySelectionCom` para que el segundo `DropdownButton` no intente buscar `_mySelectionCom` dentro de sus `items`

**Limpiar el atributo `_mySelectionCom`:**

```
 Widget _regionesContainer() {
    return new Container(
      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
        items: dataRegion.map((item) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item['ID_REGION'].toString(),
            child: new Text(item['NOMBRE_REGION'],
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)
          ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        hint: Text("Seleccione región"),
        onChanged: (String newValReg) {
          setState(() {
            _mySelectionReg = newValReg;
            _mySelectionCom = null; // <====== Agregar esta línea
            capturaComuna(newValReg);
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: _mySelectionReg,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            );
          });
        },
        value: _mySelectionReg,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto!, gracias!

Comment: Puedes indicar cómo respuesta correcta

Comment: Listo! @EdHuamani